# tools for finding errors in my jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, jquery-lint

Is there any sort of tool (online or DLable) that I could use to check my jquery code for syntax errors, unclosed {}, or other things that might cause it to not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Eray's answer above, or [jQuery Lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/) itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JsHint](http://jshint.com/) or [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

The only difference is that JsLint will check for errors as you are typing the code